# Https application not trusted

Tags: ssl, openssl, tomcat9

I have an application which I configured with Https. It gets trusted on my office laptop. When the same application is opened on another VDI within the company, it says that the application could not be trusted.
[image: My application on VDI where intermediate cert is not avialable]

This certificate is obtained from internal certification authority. We have root CA and intermediate CA set up. I noticed that the intermediate CA certificate was missing on the VDI in the Intermediate Certification Authorities section (Edge->Manage Certificates), where this is happening. But, there is another application which is configured using Https by procuring the certificate from the same internal CA and this application has no problems.
[image: Another application on the same VDI]

Note, my issue goes away if intermediate certificate is imported on VDIs. But this would be a company-wide change. So I am trying to understand what actually causes this - is this really an issue with missing certificate or did I wrongly/incompletely configure Https certificate?

This is how I configured Https for my application:

```
•   Launch an Admin command prompt
•   Run the following statements
    o   openssl.exe x509 -outform DER -in Root.cer -out Root.pem
    o   openssl.exe x509 -outform DER -in Intermediate.cer -out Intermediate.pem
    o   openssl.exe x509 -outform DER -in application-server.crt -out application-server.pem
•   Concatenated the PEM formats to a single file.
    o   type application-server.pem Intermediate.pem Root.pem > chain.pem
•   Imported this onto P12 format
    o   openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -in chain.pem -inkey application-server.key -name tcsitpdmemea > tcsitpdmemea.p12
Converted them into a JKS store giving the same passwords as provided above.
•   keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore tcsitpdmemea.p12 -destkeystore tcsitpdmemea.jks -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias tcsitpdmemea
```

Configured in Apache Tomcat as follows:

```
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="443" maxThreads="200"
           maxParameterCount="1000"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="D:\tcsitpdmemea.jks" keystorePass="tcsitpdmemea"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Please do let me know what I could be missing - I want to know where to start troubleshooting.

Comment: HTTPS servers should not only the server/leaf certificate but also the certificate chain except from the root CA certificate. It seems like you have configured your server to only send the leaf certificate and thus the intermediate CA cert is missing to build the complete chain in the web browser which makes it impossible to validate the certificate.

Comment: Adding to the above comment. Unless the intermediate certificate is installed on the devices.

Comment: @Robert Can you point me to a resource over what you are conveying. I also have an update. When I open https://hostname:8080, Tomcat shows up and the certificate comes up. But when I open my applications https://hostname:3000, this certificate does not get trusted. I feel that I am missing something specific to my application. But do you have any pointers on where to look for, please suggest.

Comment: I would check the created .p12 file in https://keystore-explorer.org if the entry contains the certificate chain or not. I would assume that the chain has to be included in the entry that also contains the server certificate and the private key. So there should be only one entry in the .p12 file.

Comment: I regenerated the P12 file with Root, Intermediate and server chain in PEM DER format along with the key. I then checked with the product vendor and they suggested to use NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS to point to a Base64 PEM file that has Root & Intermediate CA certificates in it. That resolved the issue.